# DB based Dynamic Form Generation in Flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Recently I've decide to create form creation form in Flask web app. After searching form creation found Formfield, FieldList classes in flask wtf forms and I can create the form with these classes. but it doesn't provide that I want to.

First- I am going to create a form creation form which will be help me to create form and fields on management interface.

Second- I want to be able to add the fields, not the same type of field, all different kind, such as (booleanField, StringField, IntegerField, DateTimeField etc.) because, in the form there could be different type of fields for specific reason.

Third- I want to retreive this form whenever I want to use in my view

On the DB models side;

```
class Form(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.StringField)
    fields = db.relationship('FormFields', backref='forms', lazy=True)

class FormFields(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.StringField)
    field_type = db.Column(db.StringField)
    form_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('forms.id'), nullable=False)
```

And othr tables for StrinField, BooleanField, TextField, etc. etc. should be connected this field model, and when I save the data over this created form, these data should be saved int the correct tables

The reason I am searching this, because I don't want to hardcode the Forms and fields in the code, when I need to new form or field I don't want to update code itself, it should be dynamically updated on the database.

And I want to use sqlalchemy based form creation from management page. And this will help to create anytime new form and relate the fields to the form. And on the internet still I didn't find the these style form creation for Flask, almost all of them creating dynamic for with same type of fields

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The pattern you are referring to is called EAV, or [Entity-Attribute-Value](). It is pretty hard to give a tailored advice here, as for a combination of WTForms and SQLAlchemy there's little to no existing solutions. However, for Django there exists [eav-django](https://pypi.org/project/eav-django/) which you could use for inspiration.

Comment: @NickShebanov thanks for your response, you've redirect me to the correct adress. EAV is the one that I need to implement. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Last a couple of weeks I was search how to create dynamically flask form based on models

And @nick-shebanov has been redirect me to another approach EAV impelemntation, which is really diffucult to implement. I've tried :)

And decide to create form based on dictionary, and intend to populate the related attributes from the model and pass it to form as dictionary.

What I've done so far;

```
# app.py file
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms import TextField, IntegerField, HiddenField, StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField, RadioField,SelectField
from wtforms import validators, ValidationError
    
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret123'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sqlite.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# form class with static fields
class DynamicForm(FlaskForm):
    form_type = HiddenField(default='FormType', render_kw={ 'type':'hidden' })
    # name = StringField()    

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    fields = {
        'username': 'Username',
        'first_name': 'Fisrt Name',
        'last_name': 'Last Name',
        'email': 'Email',
        'mobile_phone': 'Mobile Phone'
    }

    for key, value in fields.items():
        setattr(DynamicForm, key, StringField(value))

    form = DynamicForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print(dir(request.form))
        # print(request.form)
        dict = request.form.to_dict()
        # print(dict.keys())
        print(request.form.to_dict())
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)


# index.html template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.form_type }}

        {% for field in form if field.name != 'csrf_token' %}
          {% if field.name != 'form_type' %}
            <div>
              {{ field.label() }}
              {{ field() }}

              {% for error in field.errors %}
                <div class="error">{{ error }}</div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I can see my all fields has been rendered including hidden field. When I fill the form and post the data, I can capture it.

But still I didn't achieve to implement save the captured data into database like vertical DB modelling style yet

Here is my simple approach of DB modelling

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zou6N.png)

Is there suggestions?